# Probability of numbers being in A.P.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $ 2N + 1 $ cards numbered $1$ to $2N + 1$ . $3$ cards are picked in random without replacement. Find the probability that the numbers in the card are in arithmetic Progression.

Unfortunately I just can't understand how to even proceed.

PS it's not a homework assignment

Comment: Hint. Did you try to solve it when, say, $N=2$ ?

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. For $ n = 2 $, the number of ways was $ \binom{5}{3} $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are $\binom{2N+1}{3}$ equally likely ways to choose $3$ numbers.

Now we need to count the *favourables*. The "middle" number has to be the average of the other two. So the two end numbers must be numbers of the same **parity** (both odd or both even). Once they are chosen,  the middle number is determined.

There are $N+1$ odd numbers in our collection, and $N$ even numbers. So there are $\binom{N+1}{2}+\binom{N}{2}$ ways to choose two numbers of the same parity. This is the number of favourables.